# Clustering distance

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, machine-learning

Is there a good notion of distance between partitions of a (fixed, finite) set? The context is this: suppose I have a clustering algorithm, which clusters points using some method or other. Now, I perturb the positions of the points, the clustering changes, and I want some quantitative estimate of how much it has changed.

When there are two clusters $K_1, K_2$ which morph into $L_1, L_2,$ then it seems reasonable to look at the minimum of the sizes of $K_1 \Delta L_1$ and $K_1 \Delta L_2,$ but for more clusters it seems less clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [variation of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_information) seems to be the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: PS- You might also look at https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(01)00263-0 but IMO the variation of information is a pretty elegant and lightweight distance

Comment: An obvious question not obviously answered is: what is a "small" and what is a "large" distance?

Comment: FYI there is a reasonable way to lift a metric on PDFs to mixtures. I don’t have the reference handy but it’s in ICASSP 2000.

Comment: The aforementioned lifting is in https://doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.2000.862057